# Java - Access a class method with a dynamic name variant

Tags: java, class, dynamic-programming, static-methods

I had this problem for a while now and have managed to avoid it until now. Basically I have one class that stores information on each hole of a golf course with a getter that returns this information. In another class when a user moves from hole 1 to hole 2 (currently store as an integer), I wish to access the getter method for hole 2 but cant figure out how this would be done.

Code:

Course information class:

```
//Hole information
private static String[] hole1 = {"name", "Distance", "Par"};
private static String[] hole2 = {"name", "Distance", "Par"};

public static String[] getHole1(){
    return hole1;
}

public static String[] getHole2(){
    return hole2;
}
```

Main Class:

```
String[] holeInfo;
int currentHole = 1;

//How I call hole1 info just now
//I just access the elements of the array as needed then
holeCoOrds = course.getHole1();

//User starts next hole (this will be the case for all 18 holes)
currentHole++ 

//Call next hole information getter method here
//Something along the lines of;
holeCoOrds = course.getHole(currentHole)();
```

Any help will be appreciated, I have been racking my brain for a while now with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with reflection. However, the better way to do it is to redesign your class so that it's not necessary. Place all of your `hole` arrays into another array or list, and then make a `getHole(int)` method which returns an item from that.

So a simple (without sanity checks) version would look like this:

```
private static String[] holes = {{"name", "Distance", "Par"},
                                 {"name", "Distance", "Par"}};

public static String[] getHole(int hole){
    return holes[hole];
}
```

This makes it easy to add additional holes in the future, and lets your code be far more flexible, so that you don't need to know which hole you want at compile time.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this, Will set as accepted answer after the wait period. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont have the best approach:

```
//Hole information
private static String[] hole1 = {"name", "Distance", "Par"};
private static String[] hole2 = {"name", "Distance", "Par"};
```

Can be stored in a `List<String[]>` in this way:

```
private static List<String[]> holes = new ArrayList<String[]>();

private static String[] hole1 = {"name", "Distance", "Par"};
holes.add(hole1);
private static String[] hole2 = {"name", "Distance", "Par"};
holes.add(hole2);
```

Then, get hole value with just one method:

```
public static String[] getHole(int holeNumber){
    return holes.get(holeNumber);
}
```

---

If you want to have a better control of the holes, use a `Map` to add a *key* that identify each hole *value*:

```
private static Map<Integer, String[]> holes = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();

private static String[] hole1 = {"name", "Distance", "Par"};
holes.put(1, hole1);
private static String[] hole2 = {"name", "Distance", "Par"};
holes.put(2, hole2);
```

Then, get hole value with just one method:

```
public static String[] getHole(int holeNumber){
    return holes.get(holeNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a class for `Hole` entity like below:

```
public class Hole {
 private int holeNo;
 private String name;
 private String dist;
 private String par;

 //getters and setters for above properties
}
```

So that when you call your code from main class, it is easy to traverse through a set of Holes (2 or more).

You can even keep all the instances of Hole objects in a Map, so that retrieval is easy.